# Serialization XPObject (DevExpress) to Json

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, devexpress

I have TodoController which has a method GetTodos():

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult GetTodos()
{
    return Ok(_todoDbService.Todos());
}
```

_todoDbService.Todos() returns IEnumerable<TodoXp>.

TodoXp implentation:

```
public class TodoXp : XPObject
{
    public TodoXp(Session session) : base(session) { }

    public int Id
    {
        get { return _id; }
        set { SetPropertyValue(nameof(Id), ref _id, value); }
    }
    
    public TodoPriority Priority
    {
        get { return _priority; }
        set { SetPropertyValue(nameof(Priority), ref _priority, value); }
    }

    public string Case
    {
        get { return _case; }
        set { SetPropertyValue(nameof(Case), ref _case, value); }
    }

    private int _id;

    private TodoPriority _priority;

    private string _case;
}
```

When I call GetTodos(), I get exception:

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware[1]
      An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
System.Text.Json.JsonException: A possible object cycle was detected which is not supported. This can either be due to a cycle or if the object depth is larger than the maximum allowed depth of 32.
   at System.Text.Json.ThrowHelper.ThrowInvalidOperationException_SerializerCycleDetected(Int32 maxDepth)
   at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, Int32 originalWriterDepth, Int32 flushThreshold, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state)
   at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.WriteAsyncCore(Stream utf8Json, Object value, Type inputType, JsonSerializerOptions options, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.SystemTextJsonOutputFormatter.WriteResponseBodyAsync(OutputFormatterWriteContext context, Encoding selectedEncoding)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.SystemTextJsonOutputFormatter.WriteResponseBodyAsync(OutputFormatterWriteContext context, Encoding selectedEncoding)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResultFilterAsync>g__Awaited|29_0[TFilter,TFilterAsync](ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResultExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.ResultNext[TFilter,TFilterAsync](State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeResultFilters()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|19_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

How to correctly serialize XPObjects to Json?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XPO XPObject is not serializable due to its dependency on the non-serializable Session object. If you need to pass XPObjects over the wire you would need to use OData or create a DTO class.

Comment: Good news! In the newly released DevExpress v21.3, you can now serialize XP objects to JSON! See: [What's new in v21.1](https://www.devexpress.com/Subscriptions/New-2021-1.xml#dataaccess)